# Can the Dimensional Lock spell keep a creature stuck in a Maze spell?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, teleportation

Suppose a spellcaster casts *Maze* on a victim. On the next round, while the victim is in the maze, the spellcaster casts *Dimensional Lock* on the victim's original location. If the *Maze* duration runs out or the victim escapes, but the *Dimensional Lock* is still active, what happens?

The [*Maze*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/maze/) spell says the creature would be freed and returned to its original location:

> On escaping or leaving the maze, the subject reappears where it had been when the *maze* spell was cast.

However, the [*Dimensional Lock*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/dimensional-lock/) spell specifically prevents travel via *Maze*:

> You create a shimmering emerald barrier that completely blocks extradimensional travel. Forms of movement barred include *astral projection*, *blink*, *dimension door*, *ethereal jaunt*, *etherealness*, *gate*, *maze*, *plane shift*, *shadow walk*, *teleport*, and similar spell-like abilities. Once *dimensional lock* is in place, extradimensional travel into or out of the area is not possible.

Does this mean the victim cannot return until *Dimensional Lock* runs out?  If not, and the victim escapes the maze while the *Dimensional Lock* is active, then where do they go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### It cannot return and is stuck on the Astral Plane

As described under the [Maze](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/maze/) spell, the creature is sent to an extra-dimensional pocket dimension. But note that Maze is a [teleportation](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Conjuration) spell effect.

> School conjuration (teleportation);

As noted under Conjuration (Teleportation):

> Teleportation is instantaneous travel through the **Astral Plane**. Anything that blocks astral travel also blocks teleportation.

And on the definitions of the [Astral Plane](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/environment/the-planes/#Astral_Plane):

> Powerful spellcasters utilize the Astral Plane for a tiny fraction of a second when they **teleport**, or they can use it to travel between planes with spells like astral projection.

[Dimensional Lock](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/dimensional-lock/) prevents travel out or into the affected area, it has no effect on creatures already on an astral form moving through the area, but that doesn't allow a creature to be teleport to the Material Plane inside that specific area. Since *extradimensional travel into or out of the area is not possible*, the creature cannot be teleported back at the end of a Maze spell, regardless of what the spell says.

As also noted under the description of the *Astral Plane*:

> These three planes have one important common characteristic: each is used to get from one place to another. The Astral Plane (although technically an Outer Plane) is a conduit to all other planes, while the Ethereal Plane and the Shadow Plane both serve as means of transportation within the Material Plane, which they’re connected to. These planes have the strongest regular interaction with the Material Plane and can be accessed using various spells.

With all that said, **the creature is stuck there**. There are many ways back into te Material, bit it simply wont return to that same location where Maze was cast. They must find another way back.

Note that, while Maze is a good way to get rid of a creature for a while, this combination requires two 8th level spells to be used so it can be effective. While the same could be achieved with a single [Plane Shift](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/plane-shift) (7th level) with will save.

Also keep in mind that this is all very subjective, and while this is *my* interpretation of these rules, you might find  a GM that thinks this is very powerful and decide that the creature is *shunt* to the nearest open space outside of the *Dimensional Lock* (even if the spell isn't technically a solid object), or that returning from the *Maze* is a more specific ruling than all teleportation effects being locked. All are equally valid, as there are no rules mentioning this specific interaction or developer commentary on this specific subject.

Answer (score 3):

### Dimensional Lock would prevent the victim of a Maze spell from escaping for (up to) 10 minutes.

Because Dimensional Lock specifically references Maze, there can be no doubt about the line about its effects applying. (Emphasis added)

> Once dimensional lock is in place, extra-dimensional travel **into or out of** the area is not possible.

However, Maze has a static maximum.

> ...the maze disappears after 10 minutes, freeing the subject.

This does not rely on any form of extra-dimensional travel; the spell simply ends and the target is where it was before because there is no extra-dimension anymore.

Comment: I don't see a reason for downvoting this. This is a fine interpretation on how to handle the problem.